# I have calendar in the page, but property in the bean is a String, I got error

Tags: jsf, date, calendar, richfaces

I am using rich calendar, in the web page I should have calendar, but bean property is a string I can not change it to Date, but during save form I am always have

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Dec 09 00:00:00 GMT+04:00 2059"
java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter.getAsObject(DateTimeConverter.java:398)
org.richfaces.component.UICalendar.getAsDate(UICalendar.java:399)
org.richfaces.renderkit.CalendarRendererBase.getSelectedDate(CalendarRendererBase.java:658)
org.richfaces.renderkit.html.CalendarRenderer.doEncodeEnd(CalendarRenderer.java:451)
org.richfaces.renderkit.html.CalendarRenderer.doEncodeEnd(CalendarRenderer.java:516)
org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeEnd(RendererBase.java:134)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:861)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:242)
```

I tried a lot, but not any converter help...

any idea?

here is a converter

```
@Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) throws ConverterException {
        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss aaa";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        Date nDate = null;
        if (value == null || value.trim().length() == 0) {
            return nDate;
        }
        try {
            nDate = sdf.parse(value);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
        }
        return nDate;

    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uIComponent, Object value) {
        String date = "";
        try{
        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }
        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss aaa";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        Date dateValue = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss aaa", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(value.toString());        
        date = sdf.format((Date) dateValue);
        }
        catch(Exception e){          
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }

 but it does not work
```

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat to format the data and convert the date into  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I updated converter code, it did not help, or something wrong

Comment: My bean property is a String and I can not change it, I am saving it as a String, but using calendar, during save calendar crashed:(

Comment: Whether value is in "yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss aaa" format?

Comment: Tue Dec 09 00:00:00 GMT+04:00 2059 is not in format as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss aaa" format

Comment: from calendar user can choose also time, but I can skip it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34054/discussion-between-dheeraj-joshi-and-armen-arzumanyan)

Comment: Did nobody see that the model is in first place simply broken? OP is using a string instead of a date which is the wrong model to hold a date.

Comment: May be [this][1] could be useful if you are using RichFaces 3.3.x 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561923/richcalendar-backed-by-string-throws-exception

Answer (score 0):

try this format "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" for parsing

Answer (score 0):

Use this to convert the String to Date,

```
    String date = "15-09-2011:23:30:45";//your date
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy:HH:mm:SS");
    Date convertedDate = (Date) formatter.parse(date);
```

Comment: Whilst that works at its own in a plain Java class with a `main()` method, this does not solve OP's concrete problem at all. Look closer at the stacktrace.